# Where can I download apache module binaries from?

Tags: apache-modules, binaries, windows64

I don't have VC or an other c compiler installed on my Win7 environment.  I have located the x64 binary for Apache 2.4 but can't seem to find the same for mods.  Any idea where i can find compiled, 64 bit versions of

```
mod_ssl
mod_jk
mod_proxy
mod_proxy_ajp
mod_rewrite
mod_deflate
```

mod_cache

Answer (score 0):

So this is a big never mind.  After digging I found some of the popular Apache download stacks have modules already compiled.  I found it here:

http://www.apachelounge.com/download/